# jQuery upgrade causes an Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, highcharts, migration, typeerror, upgrade

I am working on updating jquery from 2.1.4 to 3.6.0. It looks like the update worked but on my website, the highcharts bar graph is gone, I checked "inspect" on google and I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiz5h.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.fn.chartTypeBar is not a function

at n.fn.init.jQuery.fn.hcCharts (scripts.js:37:66)

at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:425:17)

at j (jquery.min.js:2:26925)

at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:27738)

at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2:29532)

at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2:29723)
```

When I remove the jQuery update, everything works fine again (bar graph appears).

Here is the code where the error is shown:

```
! function (e) {

jQuery.fn.hcCharts = function () {

    Highcharts.setOptions({

        lang: {

            thousandsSep: ","

        }

    });

    var t = {

        lang: {

            thousandsSep: ","

        },

        title: {

            text: null

        },

        subtitle: {

            text: null

        },

        credits: {

            enabled: !1

        },

        exporting: {

            enabled: !1

        },

        chart: {

            spacing: [20, 20, 20, 20]

        },

        yAxis: {

            title: {

                style: {

                    color: "#a1a2a4",

                    fontSize: 13,

                    lineHeight: 17

                }

            }

        }

    };

   

    e(".chart-bar-h, .chart-bar-v").doesExist() && jQuery.fn.chartTypeBar(t), e(".chart-donut-1").doesExist() &&

        jQuery.fn.chartTypeDonut(t), e(".chart-area-1").doesExist() && jQuery.fn.chartTypeArea(t), e(".chart-line-1").doesExist()

        && jQuery.fn.chartTypeLine(t), e(".chart-negative-1").doesExist() && jQuery.fn.chartTypeNegative(t)

},
```

This line from the code above is highlighted as an error on the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Gae.png)

```
chartTypeBar(t), e(".chart-donut-1").doesExist() &&

        jQuery.fn.chartTypeDonut(t), e(".chart-area-1").doesExist() && jQuery.fn.chartTypeArea(t), e(".chart-line-1").doesExist()

        && jQuery.fn.chartTypeLine(t), e(".chart-negative-1").doesExist() && jQuery.fn.chartTypeNegative(t)
```

Comment: Why you don't get rid of this constructor `jQuery.fn.hcCharts`?

Comment: This is all new to me, but it looks like its needed. I tried to delete it but it did not fix the problem...the bar graphs still did not appear

Comment: I think that you should rewrite HC constructor into pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going wrong. I had placed the jQuery upgrade scripts after the other 10 or so high charts javascripts...so at the end. I moved the jQuery upgrade to the top and now my bar graphs appears and upgrade is a success.